# Balloons to space

Tags: internal-consistency, spaceships, space-travel

So we all know the traditional way to get into space is via a huge gas guzzling rocket that belches out flames, exhaust, and other potential pollutants.

So here is my proposal: we use balloons to get our rockets to the edge of space and only then do we fire up the engine. My guess is that this will limit pollution and noise to the surrounding areas and will save on fuel.

So my question is: why are we not doing this? Is there some kind of limitations that I'm not thinking of? I realize lighter than air craft don't work when there is no air, but that shouldn't keep us from using this to get to the edge of the atmosphere right?

Comment: I slightly modified your question title to reflect your actual question.

Comment: While there are proposals for different methods to get spacebound rockets to high altitudes before activating them, I think the main obstacle to balloons is the weight of spacecraft.

Comment: Has been done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockoon among others.

Comment: Balloons have the annoying habit of not staying where you put them and not going where you expect them to.  This would make an "edge of space" staging platform problematic at best.

Comment: Oh, and the other reason: it wouldn't save you very much.  Balloons can go up to say 30 miles, but the Moon is 240,000 miles away.  And the cost of boosting vs gravity will still be over .5G up until about 2000 miles elevation. Not much payoff for a lot of cost, complexity and risk.

Comment: I think you you it might be viable to get a ship strapped to a bunch of large balloons up 30 miles and let the ship carry you the rest of the way. Might use less fuel.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about Worldbuilding, but more of some sort of mixture between history, physics, and science. Perhaps you could define how this applies to your world?

Comment: There's a question about this at Space Exploration http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/could-it-be-possible-to-launch-a-rocket-from-a-balloon

Comment: @RBarryYoung but you get a lot less of air friction... the main issue is that you would need a gigantic balloon, and that is both expensive and difficult to manage

Comment: @SJuan76 Air friction is a tertiary cost, at best, in a space launch.  The primary cost is lifting against gravity.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of reasons, but here are the two big ones: Safety/control and actual utility.

Safety and control is a big issue...because you can't really steer a giant balloon very well. Once you release the balloon and send the rocket up into the sky, it's going to go wherever the wind takes it. This means that you don't necessarily know where you rocket will be, or which direction it will be facing when the thrusters light off. Obviously, this is a problem. Your rocket may end up somewhere you don't want it to be.

The second is actual utility. Using a balloon to get us to high altitude before lighting off the rocket would be useful in attaining an altitude that qualifies as being 'in space.'

However, it is going to do nothing for attaining the horizontal speed required to *stay* in space. You need to be moving at about 8 km/s (yes: per second) in order to maintain orbit. give or take, depending on how far you are from the planet.

For clarity, you need roughly

$$
10MJ/kg
$$

to lift something to the Kármán line (formal edge of space). So, now you are 'in space.' But you will remain there for a very brief moment before plummeting back to Earth. In order to stay there, you have to reach Orbital Velocity. The energy needed to manage this can be found like so...

$$
E = \frac{1}{2} m v^2
$$
$$
E = \frac{1}{2} * 1kg * 8000\frac{m}{s}^2
$$
$$
E = 32,000,000J = 32MJ
$$
Total Energy Required to get to space and stay there...
$$
≈42MJ/kg
$$

So, in conclusion...the upper end for a typical High-Altitude balloon is around 37 Km. The Kármán Line is at 100Km. Even if the balloon could get you to the Kármán Line, it would only supply you with 23.8% of the Energy needed to put something into orbit. And it's not even managing that. It's only making it about 23% of the way to the Karman Line (5.5% of the energy, if we assume a smooth energy requirement). Then we still have to exert all that force to overcome our own inertia and start accelerating...because balloons rise slower and slower the higher up they get. And, in exchange, you lose control over where the rocket goes before the engines light off. All in all, it's not terribly practical.

Note: Math ignores all the pesky things like air resistance.

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/ has some good graphics/explanations for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Energy considerations aside, it would be an operational nightmare. A balloon ascent will take hours, with a fully-fueled bird boiling off liquid oxygen or hydrogen. And any balloon-phase countdown glitches are unrecoverable - if you can't launch you lose the bird. Plus, of course, for manned flights an abort requires bailing out at an unknown altitude.

Like I say, an operations nightmare.